# How to specify time zone and other configurations while creating an EMR cluster using step function in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-emr, aws-step-functions

I am launching an EMR cluster using the step function. I need to change the timezone of the cluster from UTC to IST. While launching the cluster through AWS console, we can specify the configurations using the json format. But in the case of step functions, it is unclear that which parameter would be required to specify configurations like time zone, hadoop heapsize etc.

The basic code to launch the EMR cluster that I am using is as follows -

```
{
  "StartAt": "Create an EMR cluster",
  "States": {
    "Create an EMR cluster": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::elasticmapreduce:createCluster.sync",
      "Parameters": {
        "Name": "Sample_Cluster",
        "VisibleToAllUsers": true,
        "ReleaseLabel": "emr-5.26.0",
        "Applications": [
          { "Name": "Hive" },
          {
            "Name": "Hadoop"
          }
        ],
        "Tags": [
          {
            "Key": "Name",
            "Value": "Testcluster_emr"
          }
        ],
        "Instances": {
          "KeepJobFlowAliveWhenNoSteps": true,
          "InstanceFleets": [
            {
              "Name": "MyMasterFleet",
              "InstanceFleetType": "MASTER",
              "TargetOnDemandCapacity": 1,
              "InstanceTypeConfigs": [
                {
                  "InstanceType": "m5.xlarge"
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "Name": "MyCoreFleet",
              "InstanceFleetType": "CORE",
              "TargetOnDemandCapacity": 1,
              "InstanceTypeConfigs": [
                {
                  "InstanceType": "m5.xlarge"
                }
              ]
            }
          ],
        }
      },
      "ResultPath": null,
      "End": true
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you specify timezone in console? If yes please do share.
What we have done is, create bootstrap script to update linux timezone.

Comment: In the Software and Steps section, specify the following code in the configuration part - [{"configurations":[{"classification":"export","properties":{"TZ":"Asia/Kolkata"}}]]

Comment: @Snigdhajyoti - can you please help that how do you update the timezone in linux using script?

Answer (score 0):

The best practice here is to add a bootstrap action upon cluster creation on in your `run_job_flow` request (if you are using `boto3` library in python).

You can create a script file called `set_timezone.sh` with the following content:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo timedatectl set-timezone America/Chicago
```

When executed, this will change the server instance timezone to `America/Chicago` for example.

Then upload this script to `Amazon S3` to be used by the bootstrap action.

For the complete `run_job_flow` can be seen [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/APIReference/API_RunJobFlow.html). I just highlighting the bootstrap action part.

```
"BootstrapActions": [ 
      { 
         "Name": "Set Timezone",
         "ScriptBootstrapAction": {
            "Path": "s3://path-to-your-s3-resource/set_timezone.sh"
         }
      }
   ]
```

This way, every new instance will always have a timezone set to your need.

I believe setting bootstrap action can be done via AWS EMR cluster creation UI as well.

In fact, bootstrap action is a very powerful way to set up your cluster the way you like it. You can read more about bootstrap action [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-plan-bootstrap.html?icmpid=docs_emr_help_panel_cluster-bootstrap).